# UITableViewCell Check 1 row per section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

SUMMARY
I'm doing an app that the user will have to answer a quiz.
This quiz, may have 1-N questions, with 1-N possible answers.

MY QUESTION
How do I check just 1 cell(answer) per section(question)?
PS: I've already created the database, the tableview, etc...I just need to check this before sending the answers again to the server.

Comment: Can you post how you're creating the cells, and how you're submitting answers to your server? Are your cells like multiple choice answers and you need to check which one is selected?

Comment: Probably just deselect all the other cells in the cell's 'select' method. You'll probably want to store an array of all objects elsewhere, so you can iterate across them and deselect.

Comment: Have your data source, for each section, keep track of which row is checked.  That's what the data source is for, to track the status of the data and the display.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

-VARIABLES:

```
@property NSInteger checkedCellRow;
@property NSInteger checkedCellSection;
```

-FUNCTIONS:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (checkedCellSection == indexPath.section)
{
if (checkedCellRow == indexPath.row)
{
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
}
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
checkedCellRow = indexPath.row;
checkedCellSection = indexPath.section;
[myTable reloadData];
}
```